# Does HK2 support FieldInterceptor?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have been digging and it looks like it doesn't support doing AOP on fields. I have looked at the examples [here](https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0/aop-example.html) but the InterceptionService does not seem to support FieldInterceptor. I was looking to do some simple bean validation using a custom field annotation.

```
public Response createCustomer(@Validated final Customer customer) throws ProviderException {

}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to look inward, rather than outward. Meaning since you're already using [Bean Validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html), just write a custom validator, as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27583553/2587435), and [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13459)

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet I didn't realize that jersey supported bean validation. Once I added the jersey-bean-validation and used the (@)Valid my exception was thrown for constraint violation as expected. I am still curios why there is not an option to do FieldInterceptor with HK2 though considering AOP supports it.

Comment: We don't support Field interception because no-one has ever asked for it (until now I guess).  It'd be useful if you would put a request for it here: https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HK2 Does not support Field interception at this time.  If you would like us to add it please post a request for it [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2)